# How do I use a .NET standard 2.0 library with Framework 4.5?

Tags: vb.net, nuget, visual-studio-2022

I have found a library that I would like to use in VB.NET with Framework 4.8.

The github says that is is a .NET 4.5 library, but it also says that it is a .NET Standard 2.0 library.

[image]

When I when to import it in my VB.NET Framework 4.5 project, it says:

The package "SimpleWifi.netstandard 2.0.0" could not be installed. You are trying to install this package in a project that references ".NETFramework,version=v4.5", but the package does not contain assembly references or content files that are compatible with this framework. Contact the package creator for more information.

What could I try next?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Well.... as per the message _Contact the package creator for more information_ might be a good place to start

Comment: .NETStandard requires 4.6.1 minimum, 4.7.2 practical.  Like [nuget says](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleWifi.netstandard#supportedframeworks-body-tab).  Getting stuck on 4.5 makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: If you look a the first image you've posted, top-left corner, it says: *forked from DigiExam/simplewifi* -> the description in the About Box that mentions `.NET 4.5` is related to the original repository.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleWifi is said to be used with .NET Fragmework 4.6 or later.

[image]

If you want to install in SimpleWifi .net 4.5, change your project to .net 4.8, install SimpleWifi, and then change 4.5 again. However, other errors may occur.